# Adding extra Authentication variable form user table Community auth

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I added a new column "dummy" to usertable and made changes in 
`get_auth_data()`
declared in `Auth_Controller_set_user_variables()`

But still unable to set authentication variable.

**NOTE** I Know there is a define way to pull profile data in community autho BUT for single column i don't want to create a extra table.

Answer (score 0):

Originally Answered By @skunkbad **THANKS A LOT**

1. You add your field to the user table.
2. You modify your existing auth model (not Community Auth's auth model). If you don't have one, make one and declare it.
3. Modify your auth model's get_auth_data and check_login_status methods to return your new field.
4. If you haven't already, extend the _set_user_variables method that is in
   Auth_Controller by adding it to MY_Controller. Add your new field to
   controller properties, config values, or whatever you want.